# How to change the items in a chest

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I need to know how to change the items in the chest. If you could give me a command with all slots for PE that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @pppery This question can actually be solved with `/replaceitem` and therefor it shouldn't be marked as a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @pppery "[OK thanks, can I use replace item instead? And dose Minecraft PE have data tags?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/311844/how-to-change-the-items-in-a-chest-with-blockdata-for-pe?noredirect=1#comment442580_311849)" - The person who asked the question. It seems like the person asking the question is fine with using a different command.

Comment: @pppery "I need to now how to change the items in the chest" this is what the person wants to do, "using `/blockdata`" shows that they did some research and found a solution for the Java edition. It's worded poorly, or a bit too narrow, but the core of the question is "How do I change items in a chest?".

Answer (score 1):

This works for Pocket Edition (PE):

```
replaceitem block (x y z of chest) slot.container (slot number) (item)
```

Answer (score 0):

The command /blockdata is unavailable in minecraft pocket edition. It is impossible to change the data of a chest using commands in PE. I would suggest you use [this table](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Summary_of_commands) next time you have a question like this. It specificies which commands are available in what versions.

Comment: OK thanks, can I use replace item instead? And dose Minecraft PE have data tags?